# How to extract robust standard errors in r?

Tags: r, coefficients, robust

I calculated robust standard errors after running a regression with lm() function.

```
# robust standard errors
cov2I         <- vcovHC(ols2I, type = "HC1")
robust_se2I    <- sqrt(diag(cov2I))
print(robust_se2I)
```

I would like to extract the second value out of the resulting matrix and save it under a new variable. I've tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
stderrorols2I <- (summary(robust_se2I))[2]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput()`? So we can reprdoce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you could add RSE manually to your summary output. Alternativly, you could have a look at `coeftest()`

```
library(sandwich)  
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars) 

# robust standard errors
cov2I         <- vcovHC(mod1, type = "HC1")
robust_se2I    <- sqrt(diag(cov2I)) 

mod1 %>% 
  broom::tidy() %>% 
  mutate(rse = robust_se2I)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question.

To save the specific robust standard error I should have coded the following:

```
stderrorols2I <- (robust_se2I)[2]
```

Now it's working perfectly.
Thanks anyway for your quick feedback!